# Is it better to move 1)sub-domain to new main domain or 2)to change the sub-domain name to main domain. in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, base-url

Before we created sub-domain "steel.newtrendz.com" for magento site. after completion of the site, we planned to move the

entire sub-domain site data  "steel.newtrendz.com" to new main domain "steeloffcuts.co.nz". So we  tried to transfer 
data from "steel.newtrendz.com" to "http://steeloffcuts.co.nz/". So we got Database error as follows

"magento SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user to Database"

After lot of frustration, we changed the name "steel.newtrendz.com" to "http://steeloffcuts.co.nz/" in

Configuration>web>Unsecure> base url and in Configuration>web>secure> base url .

Is everything fine. is there any problem with this related to sub-domain & main domain or something else?

Is something else i have to change?

let me know if you have any queries in the question?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check the site now 
i hope it is working fine http://steeloffcuts.co.nz/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. ya, it's working fine. but is there anything wrong i did as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: No you did right , but you forgot to clear the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update local.xml from the

> app->etc folder

please specify the credentials you are using is it correct. 
hopt this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

I just changed the name of the domain.

I did't created any user , password, database and i did't copied my sub -domain data

to main domain. I just renamed subdomain name to main domain in admin panel.

Is evrything fine with this?

Thanks.